# Row disappears from gridview after calling the UserDeletingRow event and answering NO if I want to delete it

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a simple DataGridView on a WinForm application where I am using the UserDeletingRow event on the gridview.  When I highlight the row I want to delete, it of course prompts me if I want to truly delete the row, but if I answer "NO", the row disappears from the grid.  It's not deleted off the database, but it vanishes off the grid.  If I get out of this form, and go back in, the row is back again!  Why does it disappear in the first place?

The code of course says:  if(result == DialogResult.Yes) then I execute my DELETE statement.  That part works just fine for getting rid of the row off the database.  But I'm answering NO!

```
private void DataGridView1_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{
  if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value != DBNull.Value)
  {
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete speaker -- " + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["FIRSTNAME"].Value + " " + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["LASTNAME"].Value + "?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)  
    {  
      using (SQLiteCommand cmd = Business.Business.GetSqliteCommand())  
      {  
        string sql = "DELETE FROM Speakers WHERE ID = " + "'" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value + "'";  
        cmd.CommandText = sql;  
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  

        Main_Reload(null, null);  
      }  
    }  
  }
```

I'm expecting the grid to not do anything if I choose NO!

Comment: you should do `e.Cancel = true` in else so that it will cancel the event and will not delete the row form the GridView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an else statement to your IF block

```
else 
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    Main_Reload(null, null);
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcanceleventargs?view=netframework-4.8